# If-else statement - read if server is on or off

Tags: macos, bash, shell, if-statement

I would like to keep my remotelogin to always be "On". In this case, a .plist is called and runs a shell script (the one above) to see if RemoteLogin is Off, if so then run the following two commands; else, exit 0.

Is there something I'm missing here? Maybe "Off" needs to be replace with 0?

```
if [ `sudo systemsetup -getremotelogin` = "Off" ]; then

sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist

else 

exit 0

fi
```

Comment: What does `systemsetup -getremotelogin` return? Are those really "fancy" quotes in your script? Because they probably want/need to be normal quotes (or no quotes).

Comment: There's definitely something we're missing here. A description of what you expect to happen verses what is happening.

Comment: @JamesDean - when extra information is requested EDIT the question and ADD the requested content. People should not be expected to read all the comments to find more information. Otherwise you will just get down votes and close votes.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Thanks buddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should test for `"Remote Login: Off"` instead of just `"Off"`.

When I execute that command I get the following:

```
Blackintosh:~ jhr$ sudo systemsetup -getremotelogin
Remote Login: Off
```

Using:

```
Blackintosh:~ jhr$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.10.5
BuildVersion:   14F27
```

This is more what you want it to look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ "`sudo systemsetup -getremotelogin`" = "Remote Login: Off" ]; then
    sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on
    sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist > /dev/null 2>&1
    sudo systemsetup -getremotelogin
fi
```

I usually assign command executions to a variable like you would do for a function call and for maintainability. You usually end up needing the output multiple places in non-trivial scripts.

```
remoteLoginState=`sudo systemsetup -getremotelogin`
if [ "$remoteLoginState" = "Remote Login: Off" ]; then
...
fi
```

And make sure you set the executable flag on the script.

Comment: Right, and that works for me. However, does the script above work? as it didn't for me.

Comment: @JamesDean - one question per question, this fixes the logic. If the script still does not work then  that is another problem. Are running the script as `root`?

Comment: This is the error I get when running the shell in terminal - `line 3: [: too many arguments`

Comment: @JamesDean `[ "\`sudo ...\`" = "Remote Login: Off" ]` quote variable expansions and command substitutions.

Comment: @EtanReisner You my friend, are a genius! :)

Comment: Personally I like to assign command executions to a variable, and then use that variable. Because you probably will use the variable multiple places in most scripts.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Yes, I've seen that a lot throughout shell scripts. Thanks for the input Jarrod, I'm going to make that a habit; using _variable for maintainability_ - well said. :)

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Jarrod Roberson's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33558547/45375):

The problem was your **use of a POSIX-style conditional, `[ ... ]`, without *quoting* the LHS**:
Such conditionals are parsed with *command* syntax meaning that **the result of `` `sudo systemsetup -getremotelogin` `` - due to being *unquoted* - is subject to word-splitting and pathname expansion**:

`sudo systemsetup -getremotelogin` yields literal string `Remote Login: Off`, to which word-splitting (and pathname expansion, which happens to be a no-op here) is applied, and the shell then executes `[` as if the following had been specified:

`[ 'Remote' 'Login:' 'Off' = 'Off' ]`

As you can see, there are now *3* LHS arguments instead of *1*, which violates the syntax of the  `[` shell builtin and results in the `[: too many arguments` error you saw.

One possible fix is to double-quote the command substitution AND to fix the RHS to match the *entire* string output by the command substitution, as in Jarrod's answer.

If you're trying to write a *portable*, POSIX-compliant script, that is the way to go.

If, by contrast, you're **specifically targeting `bash`, there are better options with more flexibility**:

```
if [[ $(sudo systemsetup -getremotelogin) =~ 'Off' ]]; then
```

OR:

```
if [[ $(sudo systemsetup -getremotelogin) == *'Off'* ]]; then
```

Note how the command substitution `$(...)` (which is the superior alternative to  `` `...` ``) now does *not* need to be quoted, because `bash`'s `[[ ... ]]` construct is parsed *differently* from `[ ... ]`; however, you *may* still double-quote for the sake of consistency.

`=~` applies *extended regular-expression matching* to the *unquoted* parts of the RHS; with `'Off'` as the RHS - a *quoted* string - this effectively provides *substring* matching.

`==` applies glob-style *pattern matching* to the *unquoted* parts of the RHS and matches the *entire* LHS; `*'Off'*` therefore effectively provides substring matching too.

Comment: @JamesDean: My pleasure; glad it helped.